# Insert into boost::program_options::variables_map by index operator

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I have a `boost::program_options::variables_map` args. Now I want to insert into this map manually like a key-value pair.
Example:

```
boost::program_options::variables_map args

args["document"] = "A";

args["flag"] = true;
```

The problem is that I already have these 2 options

```
desc.add_options()
    ("document", po::value<std::string>())
    ("flag", po::value<bool>());
```

but they are given empty input from the command line sometimes. So if they are empty, then I have to update them inside the po::variables_map args itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it publicly inherits from `std::map<std::string, variable_value>` it should be relatively safe to cast it to `std::map` and use as such:

```
(*static_cast<std::map<std::string, variable_value>*>(my_variable_map))[name] = value;
```

There's no guarantee that this is enough to make `variable_map` use it, but currently it seems to be: [cpp](https://github.com/boostorg/program_options/blob/develop/src/variables_map.cpp), [h](https://github.com/boostorg/program_options/blob/develop/include/boost/program_options/variables_map.hpp).

It's annoying that this is needed.

Answer (score 4):

The library is designed to store the arguments after parsing from command line, or from a file. You cannot directly use the `operator[]` to assign values like a `std::map` because it returns a `const` reference, see the annotation [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/variables_map.html):

```
const variable_value & operator[](const std::string &) const;
```

If you *really* *really* want to assign manually the key values, you could create a `std::stringstream` and parse it with the library, see the following example program

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/program_options/options_description.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/parsers.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/variables_map.hpp>

int main()
{
  namespace po = boost::program_options;

  std::stringstream s;
  s << "document=A" << std::endl << "flag=true" << std::endl;

  po::options_description desc("");
  desc.add_options()
    ("document", po::value<std::string>())
    ("flag", po::value<bool>());

  po::variables_map vm;
  po::store(po::parse_config_file(s, desc, true), vm);
  po::notify(vm);

  std::cout << "document is: " << vm["document"].as<std::string>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "flag is: " << (vm["flag"].as<bool>() ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

If you instead just want to insert a value for some keys when they are absent, you can just use the `default_value` options as described in the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/program_options/overview.html) of `boost::program_options`.

For example:

```
  po::options_description desc("");
  desc.add_options()
    ("document", po::value<std::string>()->default_value("default_document")
    ("flag", po::value<bool>()->default_value(false));
```

Comment: Since C++11 you could use std::map's at() to access and edit a key directly.

Comment: @Simon Yes, but it throws an exception if the element does not exists. Here the question is how to *add* an element to the map.

Comment: Oops, please forget my comment. Sorry I misread the question, because I had a similar problem yesterday.

Comment: The problem is that I already have these 2 options
desc.add_options()
    ("document", po::value<std::string>())
    ("flag", po::value<bool>());

but they are given empty input from the command line sometimes.So if they are empty, then I have to update them inside the po::variables_map args itself

Comment: @etotientz In this case, just use the ```default_value``` option, see expanded answer.

Comment: @francesco, thanks for that but I cannot keep it as default since the inputs are fetched from another service after the this po::store is called.

Comment: @etotientz Perhaps you can call ```po::store``` multiple times, see [Multiple Sources](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html#id-1.3.32.4.5)

Comment: +1 to the std::stringstream solution. It is the only way not using the library internals to set a value when you cannot use `default_value` (for example when a default value of an option depends on the value of another option, like a filename)

Comment: @simon Using std::map's standard methods to add to the variables_map **spoils** some functionality; see [my answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63780447/how-to-store-data-in-boostprogram-optionsvariable-map/73628916#73628916) for a reason why that's a bad idea (the another includes another way to add to variables_map)

Answer (score 1):

Found another way to set values in `variables_map`: just to call "parent" method for operator[]

Like that:

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;

po::variables_map my_map;

std::string my_val = "smth";
boost::any my_val_any;
my_val_any = my_val;

my_map.std::map< std::string, po::variable_value >::operator[]( "key" ).value() = "value"; //or:
my_map.std::map< std::string, po::variable_value >::operator[]( "key" ).value() = my_val_any;
```